# ReactCSSTransitionGroup in child component not working

Tags: reactjs, sass, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to map over state and add a transition to each element so that the elements appear on mounting the dom.

There are two components relevant to this: PricingPage and PricingCard.

The code for PricingPage is below:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PricingCard from './PricingCard';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

class PricingPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            pricingContent:[{title:'1Abstract Art Pricing', text:`Each piece of artwork is individually priced. I base this on how much work and effort I put into the picture, basically I'm just using my own criteria.`},{title:'2Abstract Art Pricing', text:`Each piece of artwork is individually priced. I base this on how much work and effort I put into the picture, basically I'm just using my own criteria.`},{title:'3Abstract Art Pricing', text:`Each piece of artwork is individually priced. I base this on how much work and effort I put into the picture, basically I'm just using my own criteria.`},{title:'4Abstract Art Pricing', text:`Each piece of artwork is individually priced. I base this on how much work and effort I put into the picture, basically I'm just using my own criteria.`},{title:'5Abstract Art Pricing', text:`Each piece of artwork is individually priced. I base this on how much work and effort I put into the picture, basically I'm just using my own criteria.`},{title:'6Abstract Art Pricing', text:`Each piece of artwork is individually priced. I base this on how much work and effort I put into the picture, basically I'm just using my own criteria.`}]
        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className='pricing-page-wrapper'>
                <div className='navbar-background'></div>
                <h1 className='pricing-title'>Pricing</h1>
                
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="pricing" transitionEnterTimeout={700} transitionLeaveTimeout={700}>
                    <div className='pricing-wrapper'>
                    {this.state.pricingContent.map((item,i) => {
                    return(
                            <PricingCard key={item.title} title={item.title} text={item.text} />
                        )
                    })}
                    </div>
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PricingPage;
```

```css
.pricing-page-wrapper{
    min-height: 75vh;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    .pricing-title{
        color:#949494;
    } 
    .pricing-wrapper{
        opacity:1;

    }
    .pricing-enter {
        height: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .pricing-enter.pricing-enter-active {
        height: 90px;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 700ms;
    }
    .pricing-leave {
        opacity: 1;
        height: 90px;
    }
    .pricing-leave.pricing-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
        height: 0;
        transition: 700ms;
    }
}
```

PricingCard page:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

class PricingCard extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className='pricing-card'>
                <h3 className='pricing-card-title'>{this.props.title}</h3>
                <div className='pricing-card-text'>{this.props.text}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PricingCard;
```

```css
.pricing-card{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #949494;
    padding: 20px;
    height:90px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    .pricing-card-title{
        color:#949494;
    }
    .pricing-card-text{
        color:#949494;
    }
}
```

I cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must use some unique key for an item in list, it's array index won't work. You can use **item.title** for example.

You must wrap all the elements group into single *ReactCSSTransitionGroup*, not every individual element.

*ReactCSSTransitionGroup* will track them by their *key*s, so it must be mounted and have all that unique keys for group elements. So take it out of PricingCard.render to PricingPage.render.

```
 class PricingPage extends Component {
     render () {
         return (
             <div className='pricing-page-wrapper'>
                 <div className='navbar-background'></div>
                 <h1 className='pricing-title'>Pricing</h1>
                 <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="pricing" 
                 transitionEnterTimeout={700} transitionLeaveTimeout={700}>
                     {this.state.pricingContent.map((item,i) => {
                         return(
                             <PricingCard key={item.title}
                             title={item.title} text={item.text} />
                        )
                     })}
                 </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
             </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: just updated my code to do what you advised but it still wont transition in. I think it might be to do with the placement of the selectors in the scss file.

Answer (score 0):

So i added transitionAppear={true} and used the following css selectors in my scss file:

```css
.pricing-appear {
        opacity: 0.01;
      }
      
.pricing-appear.pricing-appear-active {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
      }
```

The issue was that i wanted to animate on initial mounting of the components.